# I want to make column header dynamic in react ag-grid by using value from database

Tags: reactjs, grid, ag-grid, react-grid-layout

I want to make no of columns and column header in react ag-grid dynamic  Like for example I have value coming from database as 3 so my no of columns should be 3 automatically and there name/headers should be m1, m2 , m3 respectively.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I  want make number of column dynamic as well  column like for example i have  no of question coming from my data base like 5 so my column of react ag-grid should be  M1 , M2 ,M3,M4,M5 and if no of question is 10 coming from my database then react ag-grid column would be like M1,M2,M3 ...M10 total 10 column s

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by dynamically updating the grid's column definition whenever required (in your case when you get new values from database).

Refer the [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/column-updating-definitions/) for more.

Comment: Thanks for replying actually as per documentation  in this it will be updating the column name which is initialized i want  all column name dynamic at time of initialization because the value coming from my database is different in different case i dont know the no of column at time of initialization